# Google API - request for token from Oauth2 returns null token

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-api-php-client

For credentials, I have created an developer account on https://console.developers.google.com, I have created a project and then i have created credentials from API Manager. I use "google/apiclient": "1.1.*" package. I think it is a problem with credentials.

```
    $OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = 'XXXXX-rvm1l9b1nvht9je1ic0bbe05ab5gvhbg.apps.googleusercontent.com';
    $OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = 'XXXXXXP90L_DLD3Nrc_rT4zGD';

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
    $client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
    $client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
    $redirect = url('/');
    $client->setRedirectUri($redirect);


    $token = $client->getAccessToken();
    dd($token);
```

Comment: does it request access of the user?  have you tried making a request against the api?  If memory services it doesn't fetch the first access token until it actually needs one.

Comment: It redirects to https://accounts.google.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is you're not making the request to Google to authenticate and get back the token. You should do:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
$redirect = url('/');
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect);

//redirect to google server to get the token 
return Redirect::to( $client->createAuthUrl() );
```

If the authentication succeeds, google will redirect you to the page you set with `$client->setRedirectUri($redirect)`.

In that page you can:

```
//authenticate using the parameter $_GET['code'] you got from google server
$client->authenticate( $request->input('code') );

//get the access token
$tokens = $client->getAccessToken();
```

Comment: I don't know why, but that doesn't work for me. Could you look at my question please? I've updated also with what I tried based on your answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41838484/google-oauth-access-token-not-refresh-token-null

Answer (score 9):

Tip:

Don't use:

```
$client->authenticate($authcode);
$token = $client->getAccessToken();
```

Use:

```
 $token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authcode);
```

This will at least allow you to see the error message if you dump `$token`.
In the 'Don't use:' example, if the `authenticate()` step fails, `getAccessToken()` may return null. Bad job on the API here.